Cannot create table with MUI material
import React from 'react';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
const StyledTable = () => {
    return(
        <Table> </Table>
    );
}

export default StyledTable;

I get error 'Table' is declared but its value is never read on the import row
and 'Table' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Table' on the Component in the return statement.
Here are my dependencies
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.13",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
  },


What is the extension of you component file?

@S.Marx was .ts. changed to .tsx. VS Code made it automatically into .ts. TY

Change the file extension to .tsx and reload the VS Code window.
